# Animation to collection-repeat item in Ionic Framework

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to add animation like fade-slide-in-right or slide from bottom to my ion-list item in ionic Framework Application.
So please give me hint to implement this.

I have use following code but it hides my list on device using [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

```
         <ion-content>
          <ion-list>
              <ion-item class="item-avatar animated zoomInDown list-card" collection-repeat="list in listitem" href="#/app/listitems/{{listitem.id}}">
                  <img src="{{list.Icon}}">
                  <h2>{{list.ETitle}}</h2>
                  <p>{{list.LTitle}}</p>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
          </ion-content>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ?? Any code, css, library ??

Comment: I have tried for <ion-list animation="slide-left-right" > but its not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ion-content>
  <div collection-repeat="name in names">
    <ion-item class="animated zoomInDown list-card">
      <div class="main">{{name.main}}</div>
      <div class="desc">{{name.desc}}</div>
      <div class="time">{{name.time}}</div>
      <div class="img-holder"><img ng-src="{{name.img}}"></div>
    </ion-item>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

`zoomInDown` animation is from [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) library and [stagger animation from ngAnimate](http://slides.yearofmoo.com/ng-europe-2014/index.html?29102014) 
[Here](https://popping-torch-5149.firebaseapp.com/) is a working example. Click on the `cards-list` button to start the view and list animation.

Comment: I want add animation on screen scrolling also , In codepen I used bounce animation.

Comment: This is because of ```display``` property of ```collection-repeat```. See this demo. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJZxmE It works with collection repeat

Comment: thank you its work fine but please tell me why collection-repeat not working with ion-item

Comment: ```collection-repeat``` sets ```display: absolute !important```. This is overlapping all list elements one over the other when used with ```animate.css```. Hence you are able to see only one list item being animated.

Comment: if I want to add animation on scroll then what I will do  ?

Comment: Use stagger animations. Angular's ```ngAnimation``` makes it dead simple to use this.